# How can I make safety grating stair treads less painful for bare feet?

Tags: stairs

I have some external stair runs.  They currently have "safety tread" for the stair treads. This is very safe, but hurts bare feet very much LOL.  I believe it's galvanized (I assume after the perforations are made), is there a way to make it hurt feet less somehow?

[image: safety tread grating]

Comment: Depending on why you need/have safety thread, might be able to place rubber mat/thread on top.  Is it needed just for wet conditions or also for ice/snow conditions?

Comment: Where are these installed? With a single-family house? A multi-unit dwelling? Commercial/office? Industrial?

Comment: It's a multi-unit dwelling.  My hunch is it was the cheapest thing so they installed them when cement stairs failed.  There is snow seasonally...

Comment: Is the multi-unit dwelling rentals or condo/town home where you have ownership stake? Is this a common area? If it's a rental or it's a common area, you may not have the rights to modify common use stairs. You'll be everyone's hero until someone slips or has _any_ issue with the stairs, then you'll be the scapegoat sued by the property owner/management company.

Answer (score 3):

Those are very safe till you slip and fall down. They work as a meat grinder.

There is no reason to have those unless you have heavy snow on the steps.

Consider putting stripes of outdoor carpet or rubber mat, that would not slip on top of the meat grinder.

Consider less aggressive slip preventer.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd securely fasten carpeting or mats on that. What's your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Those were never imagined for residential use.

I would use plywood cut to the size of the tread, and then to hold it down, galvanized carriage bolts, washers and nuts (sold by the pound at Tractor Supply) to put a new surface on those. On the plywood affix whatever surface material or coating you feel is appropriate for safety.

Galvanized so it doesn't cause rusting on the structure.

[image]

Carriage bolts are special bolts with a relatively flat head and a square shank designed to bite into the hole in the plywood and resist turning.  If you want *an even flatter* version of this designed to crank down flush, look into "elevator bolts"... but they won't sell those cheap at Tractor Supply by the pound!

Comment: Make sure the plywood is of an "X" variety indicating that it's for "Xterior" use or it will delaminate _very_ quickly most likely needing to be replaced annually. I'd also suggest pressure-treated plywood since this will be a horizontal surface onto which _any_ moisture that falls will stay for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Use some rubber tread mats.  You don't indicate the size of your treads, but Harbor Freight has 4x17 and 12x12 rubber mats with safety surface (the pattern like diamond plate).  They're self-adhesive, but that may not last long in an outdoor condition, so you may need to fasten them to your metal treads some other way—maybe bolts through the holes in the metal tread?  (You can also get the stuff in other sizes elsewhere.)
[image]

Comment: This seems like it would be a trip hazard on the uneven mounting surface.

Comment: Depends how you install.

Comment: Not really. Either you keep the rubber edge far enough back that you're not covering the front metal edge, or you extend it out and have a protruding edge that's likely to catch feet on the way up. I don't see a good compromise being possible.

Comment: Lap the edge of the rubber sheet over the nose of the tread.

Answer (score 1):

Belt sander.

You can easily flatten the teeth a bit with a belt sander and a medium grit belt. Keep it moving, mostly in a front-to-back motion, and try to achieve a uniform result. I'm confident that it won't take much to dramatically ease discomfort. You'll retain most of the slip resistance, too.

Comment: oooh... not  bad idea, though it might go through a lot of paper. A light touch with an angle grinder might do the trick too, though _light_ touch - it'd be easy to go overboard and accidentally grind off too much.

Comment: I had considered going at it with an angle grinder and grinding wheel but I'm concerned it might affect the galvanized aspect...

Comment: It'll wear away on top anyway. If it's aluminum it's not a concern.